# Preventing page navigation inside a Backbone-driven SPA

Tags: backbone.js, browser-history, pushstate, backbone-routing

**The justification**

In my BB app, I allow rapid input from users which gets queued & sent off periodically in the background to the server. The problem I currently have is if a user leaves the page they effectively discard any pending changes sitting in the queue.

So basically what I want to do is inform the user *before* they leave to give them the opportunity to wait for the changes to be saved rather than just exiting & discarding.

**The nitty gritty**

So for the general cases where the user refreshes or attempts to navigate to an *external* URL we can handle the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event. Where it becomes slightly tricky is when we are in the context of an SPA whereby switching between pages does not cause a page refresh.

My immediate thought was to use a global click event handler for all anchors and validate whether or not I want to allow the click, which would work for in-site link navigation. However, where this falls over is navigating via the browsers Back/Forward buttons.

I also had a look at [Backbone.routefilter](https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter), which at first glance appeared to do *exactly* what I needed. However, using the simple case as described in the [docs](https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter#returning-false-from-within-a-before-filter), the route was still being executed.

**The question**

How do we intercept navigation for all scenarios within a Backbone SPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Direct link navigation**

Use a global event handler to capture *all* click events

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="/"]', function (e) {
    var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    if (doSomeValidation()) {
        router.navigate(href, { trigger: true });
    }
});
```

**Page refreshing / external URL navigation**

Handle the `onbeforeunload` event on the `window`

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if (!doSomeValidation()) {
        return 'Leaving now will may result in data loss';
    }
});
```

**Browser back/forward button navigation**

Behind the scenes [Backbone.Router](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-169) uses the [Backbone.history](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-182) which ultimately leverages the [HTML5 pushstate API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Depending on what options you pass to [Backbone.history.start](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-197), and what your browser is capable of, the API will hook into either the `onhashchange` event or the `onpopstate` event.

Delving into the source for `Backbone.history.start` it becomes apparent that regardless of whether you are using push state or not, the same event handler is used i.e. [checkUrl](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-214).

```
if (this._hasPushState) {
    addEventListener('popstate', this.checkUrl, false);
} else if (this._wantsHashChange && this._hasHashChange && !this.iframe) {
    addEventListener('hashchange', this.checkUrl, false);
} else if (this._wantsHashChange) {
    this._checkUrlInterval = setInterval(this.checkUrl, this.interval);
}
```

Therefore, we can override this method & perform our validation in there

```
var originalCheckUrl = Backbone.history.checkUrl;
Backbone.history.checkUrl = function (e) {
    if (doSomeValidation()) {
        return originalCheckUrl.call(this, e);
    } else {
        // re-push the current page into the history (at this stage it's been popped)
        window.history.pushState({}, document.title, Backbone.history.fragment);
        // cancel the original event
        return false;
    }
};
```